# Symfony2, FOSUSERBUNDLE supporting with different user types and separate tables

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have requirement with different user type using different tables with **FOSUSERBUNDLE**.

Please anyone can help me on this.

Thank You

Comment: I need to use FOSUSER ENTITY in differnet bundles, without creating new table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multiple user types, see [PUGXMultiUserBundle](https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXMultiUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md)

Comment: Even I thought of this bundle, but I have in some of the blogs that it still have issues and not in active development.

Comment: It appears to be actively maintained.  As for issues, I wish it had user-type profile templates, but I've been able to [solve that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203590/pugxmultiuserbundle-custom-profile-template) for my own application.  IMHO, it is the best solution if one must have multiple user types.

Comment: Can you please help me suggest whether to use this bundle or [RollerworksMultiUserBundle](https://github.com/rollerworks/RollerworksMultiUserBundle)

Comment: I had more difficulty with RollerWorks documentation than with PUGXMultiUser. I also preferred that PUGX determined the user type from credentials.  RollerWorks seemed to require a user to select the appropriate login route. "Your mileage may vary".